# Error while running Tf project's executable file on android which is cross compiled for ARM 64 architecture

Tags: runtime-error, shared-libraries, tensorflow-lite, arm64, null-pointer

I am developing a Tensorflow-lite solution to be deployed on ARM-64 architecture. I cross compiled our C code using android ndk standalone toolchain. I included all the libraries which were required for compilation and successfully got a out.exe file and a out.so file on compilation. But on trying to run the .exe file on an android phone having arm64 architecture( using adb shell environment and pushed all the required libraries used during compilation and the out.so obtained ) it is giving **null pointer dereference** error.
This is the error log obtained on cmd after executing the .exe file-

```
WARNING: linker: Warning: "/data/snd/NC2/libtensorflowlite_c.so" unused DT entry: DT_RPATH (type 0xf arg 0xf68) (ignoring)
WARNING: linker: Warning: "/data/snd/NC2/libpthread.so.0" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x29 (ignoring unsupported flags)
WARNING: linker: Warning: "/data/snd/NC2/libpthread.so.0" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x29 (ignoring unsupported flags)
WARNING: linker: Warning: "/data/snd/NC2/libpthread.so.0" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x29 (ignoring unsupported flags)
WARNING: linker: Warning: "/data/snd/NC2/libtensorflowlite_c.so" unused DT entry: DT_RPATH (type 0xf arg 0xf68) (ignoring)
WARNING: linker: Warning: "/data/snd/NC2/libpthread.so.0" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x29 (ignoring unsupported flags)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is the log file obtained -

```
12-04 12:25:37.178  4209  4209 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x68
12-04 12:25:37.178  4209  4209 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
12-04 12:25:37.178  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000775bd15ff8  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000000000000001
12-04 12:25:37.178  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000008000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000080000000  x7  00000000003880f3
12-04 12:25:37.178  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x8  000000000000000a  x9  00000000000819f8  x10 000000775bd08000  x11 0000000000000020
12-04 12:25:37.178  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000018  x13 0000000000000008  x14 000000775c9e1cc0  x15 0000000000000008
12-04 12:25:37.179  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x16 ffffffffffffffff  x17 0000000000000030  x18 000000775cf20000  x19 000000775bd899f8
12-04 12:25:37.179  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000018  x21 000000000000001c  x22 0000001c00000402  x23 000000775dc89000
12-04 12:25:37.179  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000000000249430  x25 000000775bd15ff8  x26 000000775dc89000  x27 000000775be9f2b0
12-04 12:25:37.179  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     x28 000000775be95000  x29 0000007fe049c150
12-04 12:25:37.179  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     sp  0000007fe049c140  lr  000000775dbab6c0  pc  000000775bd89a00
12-04 12:25:37.193  4209  4209 F DEBUG   : 
12-04 12:25:37.193  4209  4209 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
12-04 12:25:37.193  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     NOTE: Function names and BuildId information is missing for some frames due
12-04 12:25:37.194  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     NOTE: to unreadable libraries. For unwinds of apps, only shared libraries
12-04 12:25:37.194  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     NOTE: found under the lib/ directory are readable.
12-04 12:25:37.194  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :     NOTE: On this device, run setenforce 0 to make the libraries readable.
12-04 12:25:37.194  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000081a00  /data/snd/NC2/libc.so.6
12-04 12:25:37.194  4209  4209 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 000000000003e6bc  /apex/com.android.runtime/bin/linker64 (__dl__Z19call_ifunc_resolvery+16) (BuildId: 4a559408e8da42af235cf9e971c68c35)
```

The list of libraries that I included for cross compilation are - libtensorflowlite_c.so ,libpthread.so.0, ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, libc.so.6 libc++.so ,libdl.so.2, libm.so.6, librt.so.1,libstdc++.so.6, libgcc_s.so.1. (All these libraries have Linux as the OS and arm64 as the architecture to be deployed on).